# What reason could there be for Devise not storing my users' password on signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise, save

My rails application (using Devise for authentication) allows user signup with seemingly no problems (it displays a "success" message and allows the new user to use the application during that session), however if the user signs out, they can't sign back in (a flash message says "Invalid email or password.").

Looking in the database, the reason for this looks clear: the user has been saved to the Users table (their name and email from the signup form are there), but there's nothing in the 'encrypted_password' column.

Any idea what might be causing this? I'm hoping it's something stupid and obvious that I'm not seeing for lack of sleep. ;)

I *have* generated the views for devise, as well as the registration controller. But renaming these and removing any reference to these in routes.rb doesn't solve the problem.

The Devise and user registration stuff from my User model looks like so:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #### DEVISE MODULES #### Others available are:
  #### :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false   

  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

It's probably worth noting that I switched to Devise from a custom authentication system (built following ye olde Rails Tutorial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely because of the `attr_accessor :password`. Devise already defines accessors for `password` and `password_confirmation`, you're overwriting the Devise ones.

Comment: You got it in one! Thanks so much :D